# A quien que me pueda indicar el error de este codigo?

Tags: php, html, mysql

sale esto Advertencia : mysqli_real_escape_string () espera exactamente 2 parámetros, 1 dado en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ pagwe \ menu_inicio.php en la línea 56

Advertencia : mysqli_query () espera al menos 2 parámetros, 1 dado en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ pagwe \ menu_inicio.php en la línea 58

Advertencia : mysqli_fetch_assoc () espera que el parámetro 1 sea mysqli_result, nulo dado en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ pagwe \ menu_inicio.php en la línea 59

Aviso : Variable no definida: publicaciones en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ pagwe \ menu_inicio.php en la línea 79

Advertencia : mysqli_query () espera al menos 2 parámetros, 1 dado enC: \ xampp \ htdocs \ pagwe \ menu_inicio.php en la línea 79

------------Este es el codigo------------------------------------------------------------------------

```html
<?php

include "conexion.php";

include "network-nv.php";

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION ['id_user'])){

    echo "<script>window.location='index.php';</script>";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-compatible" content="IE=edge">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ccss/menu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ccss/style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <?php echo headerb(); ?>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="box-footer">
        <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="input-group">
            <textarea name="publicacion" onkeypress="return validarn(event)" placeholder="¿Que estas pensando?" class="form-control" cols="200" rows="3" required></textarea>
            <br><br><br><br>

            <input type="file" name="foto" id="file-1" class="inputfile inputfile-1" data-multiple-caption="(count) file selected">
            <label for="file-1"><svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-briefcase" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 12.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5 14h13a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-6h-1v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-13a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-6H0v6z"/>
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 4.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.5 3h13A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 16 4.5v2.384l-7.614 2.03a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-.772 0L0 6.884V4.5zM1.5 4a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.616l6.871 1.832a.5.5 0 0 0 .258 0L15 6.116V4.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-13zM5 2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 6.5 1h3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11 2.5V3h-1v-.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5V3H5v-.5z"/>
</svg><spane>Sube foto</spane></label>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" name="publicar" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat">Publicar</button>

          </div>
        </form>
        <?php 
           if(isset($_POST['publicar']))
           {
            
            $publicacion = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['publicacion']);

            $result = mysqli_query("SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE 'Name' = 'publicaciones'");
            $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $next_increment = $data['Auto_increment'];

            $alea = substr(strtoupper(md5(microtime(true))), 0,12);
            $codigo = $next_increment.$alea;

            $type = 'jpg';
            $rutafoto = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
            $name = $codigo.".".$type;

            if(is_uploaded_file($rutafoto))
            {
                $destino = "publicaciones/" .$name;
                $nombre = $name;
                copy($rutafoto, $destino);
            }
            else{
                $nombre = '';
            }

            $subir = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO publicaciones (comentarios,fecha_p,contenido,imagen,comentarios) values ('".$_SESSION['id_user']."',now(),'$publicaciones', '$nombre','1')");
            if($subir) {
                echo '<script>window.location"menu_inicial.php"</script>';
            }


           }
           ?>



      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por otro lado consultar la doc. Siempre es algo bueno https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Claramente te dice que le debes enviar dos parametros y le estas enviando uno, lee la documentación de PHP que te envía BetaM

Comment: @LuisAlfredoSerranoDíaz, la verdad intente mucho eso y sigue igual, si me puedes escribir correctamente el código, quedare muy agradecido.

Comment: Estás seguro que en la variable `$_POST['publicacion']` te esta llegando data porque la variable que estás validando su contenido es otra `$_POST['publicar']`